# Joomla article showing an unwanted 1 one every page

Tags: joomla

It's been over a month now of me trying to find help for my site, not a single person has been able to help me. I believe if someone were to simply go on the backend of my site, then perhaps it could be fixed quickly.

My issue is I have an article that's showing a 1 on every page. I believe that '1' was replaced by a former developer where perhaps the article title went. When I hover over it with Firebug, it's showing:

```
<div class="item-page">
1
<p></p>
</div>
```

I've personally spent about 9 hours now trying to find it. I've been suggested to look in the template area many times. The 1 still shows up in the articles when I switch templates. Not that it seems to matter, I'm using Rockettheme.

Please don't recommend I simply go to the article manager and fix it; that's the first place I looked. Remember, it's showing up for every Single Article.

I would deeply appreciate any help; I'm in a bit of a desperate situation here.

Thank you for your time!!

I'm not sure why my question was voted down?

Answer (score 0):

That's a bug that existed many many years ago. You need to update to the current version of Joomla. (Not migrate--update to the current release of your version)

Comment: Oh ok. I'm using 2.5.7 I'm assuming I need to upgrade to 3.0?

Comment: no, you don't need to upgrade to 3.0. Joomla 2.5 is still the recommended version to use as 3.0 is the short release version.

Comment: So you want me to upgrade to 2.5 when I'm already using 2.5.7? How does that make any sense?

Comment: According to [Joomla Downloads](http://www.joomla.org/download.html), Joomla 2.5.7 is the current version.  Could the problem be a configuration file from an old version that has not been upgraded or replaced?

Comment: which layouts is this happening in? 
Can you check whether your template is using layout overrides?

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler  This is a new site so 2.5.7 was used for the initial install.   I do use a template from Rockettheme so I'm not sure if that's the answer you're looking for. There is nothing other than that which would override it.. I use standard articles and modules with Joomla.

Comment: @user1772801: I can spell Joomla; Google found its home for me.  That's pretty much the limit of my knowledge of what it is.  Why don't you try a different theme and see if the problem goes away?  If so, we can guess that it is a problem with or property of the Rockettheme.  But this is pure speculation on my part — applying common sense (or the experience from a long time working with software) to an unknown product.

Comment: Rockettheme uses a ton of overrides so it it probably something in there. Try switching to one of the core templates (like Beez_20) and see if the problem goes away. Also Rockettheme has a pretty good support forum if it seems like a problem with their template.

Comment: As I said in my OP, I have switched templates. The fact that it stays there even with the core default template proves that it's likely not to do with Rockettheme.

Comment: You still haven't said if your template is using overrides or not.

Comment: @elin I'm sorry, it does use overrides. It's Rockettheme, they use many overrides for their templates.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling all content plugins and see if it goes away. One of the content plugins may be adding content to the articles.